# How to describe the equivalence class for this equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

For $x, y \in R$, define $x \sim y$ as the equivalence relation meaning $x-y \in Z$.

Am I right in thinking that the relation on $R$ splits it up into different equivalence classes? And that in this case there should be an infinite amount of $[x]=\{x+n$ | $n \in Z, x  \in [0, 1)\}$? I am not too familiar with equivalence classes so any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You're perfectly right. There's exactly one representative of each class in the interval $[0,1)$. Note the result is homeomorphic (as a topological space) to the circle $S^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be an infinite (uncountable) number of equivalence classes. Your set description of it is correct.

Comment: In other words, yes you're right.